# Create a realistic start_date and ebd_date

Tags: oracle, function, date

I have a function below, which works fine and generates a random date.

I'm trying to pair a start_date with and end_date for the same row. Is there a mechanism I can use in SQL where I can add random intervals hours, minutes,  seconds to the start_date to ensure the end_date is at least 1 hr greater and less than 10 hours than the start_date?

For example, say I want to populate the table below. I am open to using a function, package type if need be.

Thanks in advance to all who respond.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_date(
      p_from IN DATE,
      p_to   IN DATE
    ) RETURN DATE
   IS
   BEGIN
      RETURN p_from + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() * (p_to - p_from + 1 );
END random_date;
/


CREATE TABLE t1 (     
 seq_num NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
   start_date   DATE,
   end_date    DATE 
);

/* here I need help with end_date */

 INSERT INTO t1 (start_date, end_date)
        SELECT
            random_date(DATE '2022-04-01', DATE '2022-04-30'),
 FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= 50;
```

Comment: It's possible that your random date will include a time that doesn't actually exist where you are - e.g. if it generated 2022-03-27 01:30:00 then that would be a perfectly valid date value but if you're in the UK then that doesn't actually exist as it's in the GMT/BST cutover hour. And adding an interval could also put the end date in that missing hour. The *date* won't complain as it isn't timezone-aware. If it matters to you then you'd need to handle that somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gen_dates(i_from_date IN DATE, i_end_date IN DATE, i_min_delta IN NUMBER, i_max_delta IN NUMBER, i_num_rows IN NUMBER) 
RETURN VARCHAR2 
SQL_MACRO 
IS 
BEGIN 
RETURN q'{
SELECT start_date, end_date, 
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM (CAST(end_date AS TIMESTAMP) - CAST(start_date AS TIMESTAMP))) || 'Days' || 
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (CAST(end_date AS TIMESTAMP) - CAST(start_date AS TIMESTAMP))) || 'Hours' || 
    EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (CAST(end_date AS TIMESTAMP) - CAST(start_date AS TIMESTAMP))) || 'Minutes' || 
    EXTRACT(SECOND FROM (CAST(end_date AS TIMESTAMP) - CAST(start_date AS TIMESTAMP))) || 'Seconds' as formated_delta FROM ( 
        SELECT pivot_date AS start_date, pivot_date + NUMTODSINTERVAL( i_min_delta + (i_max_delta-i_min_delta) * DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(), 'hour') AS end_date 
        FROM (
            SELECT pivot_date + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() AS pivot_date            
            FROM ( 
                SELECT rownum AS rn, pivot_date AS pivot_date FROM ( 
                    SELECT TRUNC(i_from_date)+level-1 AS pivot_date FROM DUAL 
                    CONNECT BY TRUNC(i_from_date)+level-1<=TRUNC(i_end_date) 
                ) 
            ) 
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= i_num_rows AND PRIOR rn = rn AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL 
        )
    ) 
}' ; 
END;
/
    
    SELECT count(*) FROM gen_dates( to_date('01-4-2022','dd-mm-yyyy'), to_date('03-4-2022','dd-mm-yyyy'), 1, 10, 100000) 
    ;
    -- 300000 
    
    SELECT count(*) FROM gen_dates( to_date('01-4-2022','dd-mm-yyyy'), to_date('03-4-2022','dd-mm-yyyy'), 1, 10, 100000)
    WHERE (end_date - start_date < 1/24) OR (end_date - start_date > 10/24)
    ;
    -- 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra effort but as I mentioned I want different times for the same start_date. In your solution the times are the same for each day

Comment: Thanks for the extra effort but as I mentioned I want different times for the same start_date. In your solution the times are the same for each day. 

Imagine I have workers that have to punch a time card at the beginning and end of their shifts to get paid. They aren't ALL going to punch in at  the same time, 08:58:43. The same thing applies for the punch out time. They all will not clock out at 17:01:44. I want to simulate a bunch of different start and end times for each day in a given range. I hope that clarifies my requirement.

Comment: Then just add a level in the queries, to add the random time between the generation of the rows and the generation of start/ end date, see the edited version above.

Comment: The count(distinct start_date) give around 177K and count(distinct start_date || end_date) gives around 299K out of the 300K generated.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks for your time patience and expertise

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it, one query won't do because you have to check whether difference of randomly fetched start and end date match criteria. Therefore, a PL/SQL block which - in a loop until counter hits the limit of 50 rows (taken from your `connect by` clause) - validates dates and inserts a row only if difference is between 1 and 10 hours:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_cnt         NUMBER := 0;
  3     l_start_date  DATE;
  4     l_end_date    DATE;
  5  BEGIN
  6     WHILE l_cnt < 50
  7     LOOP
  8        SELECT random_date (DATE '2022-04-01', DATE '2022-04-30') start_date,
  9               random_date (DATE '2022-04-01', DATE '2022-04-30') end_date
 10          INTO l_start_date, l_end_date
 11          FROM DUAL;
 12
 13        IF l_end_date - l_start_date BETWEEN 1 / 24 AND 10 / 24
 14        THEN
 15           INSERT INTO test (start_date, end_date)
 16                VALUES (l_start_date, l_end_date);
 17
 18           l_cnt := l_cnt + SQL%ROWCOUNT;
 19        END IF;
 20     END LOOP;
 21  END;
 22  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Result:

```
SQL> SELECT seq_num,
  2         start_date,
  3         end_date,
  4         ROUND ((end_date - start_date) * 24, 1) diff_hours
  5    FROM test;

   SEQ_NUM START_DATE       END_DATE         DIFF_HOURS
---------- ---------------- ---------------- ----------
         1 08.04.2022 11:14 08.04.2022 18:49        7,6
         2 14.04.2022 19:23 14.04.2022 23:06        3,7
         3 13.04.2022 12:12 13.04.2022 16:06        3,9
         4 24.04.2022 13:04 24.04.2022 16:03          3
         5 01.04.2022 12:52 01.04.2022 19:29        6,6
         6 08.04.2022 08:24 08.04.2022 12:56        4,5
         7 29.04.2022 22:05 29.04.2022 23:22        1,3
         8 20.04.2022 05:35 20.04.2022 10:31        4,9
         9 23.04.2022 00:52 23.04.2022 08:46        7,9
        <snip>
        46 05.04.2022 20:06 06.04.2022 01:52        5,8
        47 11.04.2022 20:03 12.04.2022 05:11        9,1
        48 12.04.2022 17:07 12.04.2022 23:13        6,1
        49 30.04.2022 09:32 30.04.2022 13:42        4,2
        50 12.04.2022 00:24 12.04.2022 10:19        9,9

50 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: This seems quite inefficient, but you could improve things quite a bit by avoiding the context switching of selecting from dual, and reduce the number of iterations from about 80 per value to something significantly lower by using the start date as the lower bound for the end date - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=3718d60a5f0cee340efe1a098cd16ed5).

Comment: (It also allows exactly 10 hours where the question said less than - which might be OK and is easily fixed anyway; and you seem to be intentionally restricting the end date to be within the month as well as the start date, which the question didn't mention but might be what the OP wants - though that seems less realistic to me.)

Comment: @Alex, I presumed that the OP wants to keep their function and use dates as in the *original* INSERT statement (1st and last of April 2022). If I were the OP, I'd rather accept your answer than mine.

Comment: Yeah, I kept the start date in that range; but I don't necessarily see that a start date after 2pm on the 30th can't carry over and end on May 1st, which you are preventing. But that may be correct, who knows *8-)

Comment: Thank you both for your expertise and insight. There is no set limit in the random date range that can be passed.  Its perfectly acceptable for the end date to go into the next month.  My overall goal is to write a function that will RETURN a string denoting of NdaysNHoursNMinutesNSeconds which represents the difference from end_date-start_date

Comment: @Beefstu - that's wandering rather a long way from the question, but I've added a way to do that to my answer just for fun...

Answer (score 2):

You could add a function to generate a random interval within the 1 and 10 hour limits, and add that to the start date - which would need an inline view or CTE as you need to refer to the random start date twice to do the calculation:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_interval(
      p_min_hours IN NUMBER,
      p_max_hours IN NUMBER
    ) RETURN INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
   IS
   BEGIN
      RETURN floor(dbms_random.value(p_min_hours, p_max_hours)) * interval '1' hour
        + floor(dbms_random.value(0, 60)) * interval '1' minute
        + floor(dbms_random.value(0, 60)) * interval '1' second;
END random_interval;
/
```

and then

```
INSERT INTO t1 (start_date, end_date)
WITH cte (start_date, duration) AS (
    SELECT
        random_date(DATE '2022-04-01', DATE '2022-04-30'),
        random_interval(1, 10)
    FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= 50
 )
SELECT start_date, start_date + duration
FROM cte;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ecd048648120dd5f5f26859860dbc0ec)

In recent versions of Oracle you don't need either permanent function, if this is all they will be used for; you can [define them within the `WITH` clause](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1#functions):

```
INSERT /*+ WITH_PLSQL */ INTO t1 (start_date, end_date)
WITH 
FUNCTION random_date(
      p_from IN DATE,
      p_to   IN DATE
    ) RETURN DATE
   IS
   BEGIN
      RETURN p_from + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() * (p_to - p_from + 1 );
END random_date;
FUNCTION random_interval(
      p_min_hours IN NUMBER,
      p_max_hours IN NUMBER
    ) RETURN INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
   IS
   BEGIN
      RETURN floor(dbms_random.value(p_min_hours, p_max_hours)) * interval '1' hour
        + floor(dbms_random.value(0, 60)) * interval '1' minute
        + floor(dbms_random.value(0, 60)) * interval '1' second;
END random_interval;
cte (start_date, duration) AS (
    SELECT
        random_date(DATE '2022-04-01', DATE '2022-04-30'),
        random_interval(1, 10)
    FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= 50
 )
SELECT start_date, start_date + duration
FROM cte;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=15723a48b03c933fc969e2e53282c0c3)

---

> My overall goal is to write a function that will RETURN a string denoting of NdaysNHoursNMinutesNSeconds which represents the difference from end_date-start_date

That isn't really anything to do with what you asked, but it's fairly simple if you treat the dates as timestamps, and extract the elements from the interval value you get from subtracting those:

```
create function diff_as_string (p_from date, p_to date)
return varchar2 is
  l_interval interval day(3) to second(0);
begin
  l_interval := cast(p_to as timestamp) - cast(p_from as timestamp);
  return extract (day from l_interval) || 'Days'
    || extract (hour from l_interval) || 'Hours'
    || extract (minute from l_interval) || 'Minutes'
    || extract (second from l_interval) || 'Seconds';
end diff_as_string;
/
```

At least as long as the elapsed time is less than 1000 days, which would exceed the range allowed by that interval type.

And again you could define that function in a `WITH` clause instead; or it could be done just as a query, maybe with a normal CTE or inline view to avoid repeatedly converting the data:

```
select seq_num, start_date, end_date,
  extract (day from diff_interval) || 'Days'
    || extract (hour from diff_interval) || 'Hours'
    || extract (minute from diff_interval) || 'Minutes'
    || extract (second from diff_interval) || 'Seconds' as diff
from (
  select seq_num, start_date, end_date,
    cast(end_date as timestamp) - cast(start_date as timestamp) as diff_interval
  from t1
)
order by seq_num;
```

| SEQ_NUM | START_DATE | END_DATE | DIFF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20-APR-2022 03:46:04 | 20-APR-2022 07:44:30 | 0Days3Hours58Minutes26Seconds |
| 2 | 12-APR-2022 01:37:07 | 12-APR-2022 10:54:40 | 0Days9Hours17Minutes33Seconds |
| 3 | 12-APR-2022 16:20:44 | 12-APR-2022 20:36:13 | 0Days4Hours15Minutes29Seconds |
| 4 | 03-APR-2022 01:24:53 | 03-APR-2022 07:57:52 | 0Days6Hours32Minutes59Seconds |
| 5 | 01-APR-2022 21:33:20 | 01-APR-2022 23:50:13 | 0Days2Hours16Minutes53Seconds |
| ... |  |  |  |
| 50 | 22-APR-2022 22:46:46 | 23-APR-2022 08:03:38 | 0Days9Hours16Minutes52Seconds |
| 9999 | 21-NOV-2019 00:00:01 | 17-AUG-2022 00:00:00 | 999Days23Hours59Minutes59Seconds |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ad35545363badd9e5c396af1efacdc8d) with and without a function.

Answer (score 1):

If your version of ORACLE is recent enough, you can use a SQL_MACRO to avoid context switches (and any way you don't need PL/SQL at all since you can INSERT .. FROM SELECT...):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gen_dates(i_from_date IN DATE, i_min_delta IN NUMBER, i_max_delta IN NUMBER, i_delta_type IN VARCHAR2, i_num_rows IN NUMBER)
RETURN VARCHAR2
SQL_MACRO
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN q'{SELECT start_date, end_date, EXTRACT(DAY FROM (CAST(end_date AS TIMESTAMP) - CAST(start_date AS TIMESTAMP))) || 'Days' ||
 EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (CAST(end_date AS TIMESTAMP) - CAST(start_date AS TIMESTAMP))) || 'Hours' ||
 EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (CAST(end_date AS TIMESTAMP) - CAST(start_date AS TIMESTAMP))) || 'Minutes' ||
 EXTRACT(SECOND FROM (CAST(end_date AS TIMESTAMP) - CAST(start_date AS TIMESTAMP))) || 'Seconds' as formated_delta FROM (
  SELECT i_from_date AS start_date, i_from_date + NUMTODSINTERVAL( i_min_delta + (i_max_delta-i_min_delta) * DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(), i_delta_type) AS end_date FROM DUAL 
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= i_num_rows)}' ;
END gen_dates;
/

SELECT * FROM gen_dates( TO_DATE('2022-04-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), 1, 10, 'hour', 200 ) ;

01-APR-2022 00:00:00    01-APR-2022 08:54:05    0Days8Hours54Minutes5Seconds
01-APR-2022 00:00:00    01-APR-2022 08:32:28    0Days8Hours32Minutes28Seconds
01-APR-2022 00:00:00    01-APR-2022 02:17:42    0Days2Hours17Minutes42Seconds
01-APR-2022 00:00:00    01-APR-2022 03:24:33    0Days3Hours24Minutes33Seconds
01-APR-2022 00:00:00    01-APR-2022 03:28:17    0Days3Hours28Minutes17Seconds
01-APR-2022 00:00:00    01-APR-2022 09:31:37    0Days9Hours31Minutes37Seconds
01-APR-2022 00:00:00    01-APR-2022 05:04:53    0Days5Hours4Minutes53Seconds
01-APR-2022 00:00:00    01-APR-2022 04:15:49    0Days4Hours15Minutes49Seconds
01-APR-2022 00:00:00    01-APR-2022 02:16:10    0Days2Hours16Minutes10Seconds
01-APR-2022 00:00:00    01-APR-2022 04:49:56    0Days4Hours49Minutes56Seconds
01-APR-2022 00:00:00    01-APR-2022 06:46:32    0Days6Hours46Minutes32Seconds
01-APR-2022 00:00:00    01-APR-2022 02:18:45    0Days2Hours18Minutes45Seconds
01-APR-2022 00:00:00    01-APR-2022 05:38:22    0Days5Hours38Minutes22Seconds
01-APR-2022 00:00:00    01-APR-2022 08:57:54    0Days8Hours57Minutes54Seconds
01-APR-2022 00:00:00    01-APR-2022 03:17:17    0Days3Hours17Minutes17Seconds
01-APR-2022 00:00:00    01-APR-2022 05:59:49    0Days5Hours59Minutes49Seconds
01-APR-2022 00:00:00    01-APR-2022 04:03:42    0Days4Hours3Minutes42Seconds
01-APR-2022 00:00:00    01-APR-2022 08:40:43    0Days8Hours40Minutes43Seconds
...
```

(and if you have an even more recent version of ORACLE you can make of the formatting expression a SQL_MACRO(SCALAR))

Comment: While your solution is nice, neat and eloquent how would it handle a range of dates say 2022-04-01 to 2022-04-03. Btw I'm running Oracle 19.2

Comment: If you change specifications at each new answer, we may go forever...
What do you want exactly now ?
No more a minimum delta and the max between the diff between the 2 dates ?
Just adapt the calculation of the NUMTODSINTERVAL parameter.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond . Your solution is almost perfect except that I want a random start_date from 00:00:00 to 23:59;59. If you look at my post I call the function random_date to populate the start_date. The end_date should ALWAYS be greater then the start_date. If the end_date crosses midnight and is on a different date that would be fine. Lastly, I need this to handle a range of  consecutive start dates, say from 2022-04-01 to 2022-04-03 for example. It doesn't matter if this is put into a wrapper around your function or called as an argument. Thanks for your expertise

Comment: "from 00:00:00 to 23:59;59" is not a date : it's a time interval...
your random_date function gets a fixed date as input and then generates a random one to be the end_date, and your INSERT can't work because you must supply the 2 values...

Comment: You still don't explain clearly the specification of the start_date: you just say that it can be any time of "some day"... 
Do you mean: I give a (truncated) date then I want to generate randomly hour/min/sec that day and generate another date between 1 and 10 hours after that generated one ?
Then you just adapt the function to TRUNC the i_from_date and add randomly generated hours between 0 and 23:59:29...
You just have to use that expression twice since i_from_date is used twice in the formula.

Comment: I want the start_date for each row to be like this dbms_random.value(0, 86400) seconds; and the end_date = start_date+NUMTODSINTERVAL… the way you laid it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247545/discussion-between-beefstu-and-p3consulting).